# Always use the right tool for the job & a bad workman blames his tools

Tags: meaning

These two phrases

- A bad workman blames his tools
- Always use the right tool for the job

Seem to contradict each other. Are the just opposite sides of the same coin, or is there scope for both being applicable to a single given situation?

Comment: Can you expand on why you think they are contradictory?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is based on a false premise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing those two phrases have in common is that they both reference using tools. That's all! They are not opposites and they are not linked in meaning.

> A bad workman blames his tools

means that someone who has done something badly or in a wrong way would rather blame the tools they used for the bad quality of what they have done than admit that they were at fault.

> Always use the right tool for the job

means that you should always pick the equipment, person, etc that is most suitable for the job you are trying to do i.e don't try to pound nails with a screwdriver.

Technically, there could exist a situation in which both phrases are applicable but it would not be because they mean the same thing.

Comment: Mostly true, but I disagree that they are not linked.  There are at least two possible interpretations of the first expression:
(a) it is in fact not the fault of the tools, but the lack of skill of the workman to use said tools correctly
(b) the workman lacks the skill or can't be bothered to choose the most appropriate tool for the job - which is directly linked to the second expression.

Answer (score 1):

These phrases are unrelated in meaning, though they do appear somewhat similar.

"A bad workman blames his tools" means that it's common for people to blame their mistakes on their tools, as if the tools were faulty, instead of their user, the workman.

While "always use the right tool for the job" is different because it's not about  *faulty* tools, just *different* ones. It's not about whether the tools used work, it's about using the right tool for the situation.

Compare (using a literal interpretation):

- "Argh, this stupid hammer keeps bending the nails!" and
- "Why are you using a hammer to drive in screws!?"

The first one is using a hammer correctly, but blaming the hammer for a poor job of the worker. The second one is having poor results because the hammer is being misused- the right tool for the job would be a screwdriver.